# Why playing game consumes more battery than reading book?

Tags: ipad, battery

I'm confused. I have an ipad mini 2. When I'm reading a book *(noted that WiFi is also on)*, my ipad consumes less battery than when I'm play clash of cleans. Why? in both cases there is both [a bright screen] and [WiFi is on] .. So why they doesn't use of the battery equally ?

Based on the tests, my ipad's battery will be finished after: *(continuous)*

- 11 hours reading
- 9 hours gaming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CoC app is using the iPad's CPU, RAM and graphics drivers to a much greater extent than merely opening a text file, applying a little font and page formatting, and displaying a rather static image until you swipe the page.

An analogy would be the gasoline consumption of an automobile idling at a stop sign (reading a book on iPad) compared to the same automobile traveling at 90MPH (playing CoC on iPad.)